# Javascript - Error when accessing an associative array value

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, for-loop

I have an array, locations:

```
{
   "locations":[
      "{\"location_id\":\"1\",\"location_name\":\"Main Office\"}",
      "{\"location_id\":\"6\",\"location_name\":\"Secondary\"}"
   ]
}
```

I am trying to loop through this array to display the location id/name, but keep getting undefined errors.

```
for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; ++i) {
    alert(locations[i].location_id);
}
```

If I do `alert(locations[i])`, I can see the individual array contents for that index, but seemingly have no way go any further.

I feel like I'm missing something incredibly simple and would appreciate any help. Everything I've read suggests I should just be able to get the value of the array by using the for [i] loop.

Comment: The elements in `"locations"` are JSON. You have to parse it first into actual objects.

Comment: Which raises the question: why are the elements JSON in the first place?

Comment: I'm parsing the array with JSON.parse(). The elements are in JSON as they're being retrieved via a jQuery.get call. For everything else I've done this with it's just been sufficient to reference like locations.location_id but this is the first time I've tried using more than one element in the array - using the [i], etc.

Comment: _"The elements are in JSON as they're being retrieved via a jQuery.get call"_ - That's not the source of the problem. The back-end converts them to JSON twice - for no good (obvious) reason. Either parse them -> `JSON.parse()` or don't convert them to JSON twice.

Comment: "The back-end converts them to JSON twice - for no good (obvious) reason" - Yep, that was it. Thank you, @Andreas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will list all the noticeable problems in your query

1. "locations" array seems to be a part of another object
2. All elements of "locations" array are of type `String` hence the `locations[i].location_id` would not work as the "dot" operator expects an object

Suggestions

1. Make sure "locations" is an array of objects which is properly formatted for eg:

```
let locations = [
    { location_id: 1, location_name: 'Main office'},
    { location_id: 2, location_name: 'any name' },
];
```

Answer (score 0):

define it like:

```
let locations = [
    { location_id: 1, location_name: 'Main office'},
    { location_id: 2, location_name: 'any name' },
];

locations.forEach(location => {
    alert(location.location_id);
});
```

Or if your data is in json format:

```
let json = '{ "locations": [ { "location_id": 3, "location_name": "Name" } ]}';

const data = JSON.parse(json);

data.locations.forEach(location => {
    console.log(location.location_id);
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment, this is a much better implementation of the forEach loop.